# Number of Customer Purchases in Their First Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by, window-functions

I have a list of customer orders. I can easily calculate the month and year of first purchase for each customer (e.g. customer 1 had their first purchase in Sept 2021, customer 2 had their first purchase in Oct 2021, etc.). What I want to add is an additional column that counts the number of purchases a customer made in their first month.

Existing data table (Orders):

| OrderId | CustomerId | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9/15/2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 10/15/2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 11/1/2021 |
| 4 | 2 | 10/1/2021 |
| 5 | 2 | 10/6/2021 |
| 6 | 2 | 10/7/2021 |
| 7 | 2 | 11/9/2021 |
| 8 | 3 | 11/15/2021 |

Desired output:

| CustomerId | FirstOrderMonth | FirstOrderYear | FirstMonthPurchaseCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | 2021 | 3 |
| 3 | 11 | 2021 | 1 |

I was thinking something like this for the first three columns:

```
SELECT o.CustomerId,
MONTH(MIN(o.OrderDate)) as FirstOrderMonth,
YEAR(MIN(o.OrderDate)) as FirstOrderYear
FROM Orders o
GROUP BY o.CustomerId
```

I am not sure how to approach the final column and was hoping for some help.

Comment: would you rather just count by month and not maybe by month ahead of the date? If someone's date is September 29th then wouldn't you rather count it until October 29th?

Comment: For my case no. For this application I specifically want the month so only until the end of September

Comment: Cool. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate by the customer's id, the year and the month of the order and use window functions to get the year and month of the 1st order and the count of that 1st month:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId,
       FIRST_VALUE(MONTH(OrderDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)) FirstOrderMonth,
       MIN(YEAR(OrderDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId) FirstOrderYear,
       FIRST_VALUE(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)) FirstMonthPurchaseCount
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustomerId, YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=12712968e7c80b7986040ce6911182f6).

Answer (score 1):

```
select   CustomerId
        ,min(month(OrderDate))   as FirstOrderMonth
        ,min(year(OrderDate))    as FirstOrderYear
        ,count(first_month_flag) as FirstMonthPurchaseCount
        
from    (select *
                ,case when month(OrderDate) = month(min(OrderDate) over(partition by CustomerId)) then 1 end as first_month_flag
         from Orders) Orders

group by CustomerId
```

| CustomerId | FirstOrderMonth | FirstOrderYear | FirstMonthPurchaseCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | 2021 | 3 |
| 3 | 11 | 2021 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a6218a13ed74888bc3d02725fc89f59&hide=1)

Comment: For line 2 / 3 should it be month(min( instead of min(month( ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `RANK()` function to identify the first month purchases for each user as the following:

```
Select D.CustomerId, MONTH(OrderDate) FirstOrderMonth, 
       YEAR(OrderDate) FirstOrderYear, COUNT(*) FirstMonthPurchaseCount
From
(
  Select *, RANK() Over (Partition By CustomerId Order By YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)) rnk
  From table_name
) D
Where D.rnk = 1
Group By  D.CustomerId, MONTH(OrderDate), YEAR(OrderDate)
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9b142532e346960dd5fbe3b15e34fd67).

If you want to find second, third ... month purchases, you may use the `DENSE_RANK()` function instead of `RANK()` and change the value in the where clause to the required month order.